# c++ loop at exact time intervals

Tags: c++, timing

I've got the similar problem as [python - loop at exact time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221522/python-loop-at-exact-time-intervals) - the only difference is that I want to use C++.

So: how is it possible in C++ to make a loop in which every iteration would take a set amount of time, independently of the time of executing code in a loop?

```cpp
// Example:
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cout << "foo" << endl; // prints foo every, let's say, 1s
    bar(); // may take, let's say 1ms or 325ms (of course less than 1s)
}
```

Comment: You do it the same way as in the linked question. The only difference is that you do that in C++ and find [the appropriate standard library utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

Comment: The idea how to do that in c++ is merely the same as in the python style question you linked. Have a look at the facilities provided with standard c++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread